# Print value on a Label when clicked on a link

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a Label declared as follows;

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=" "></asp:Label>
```

Furthermore, i have link declared as followed;

> `<a> Hello </a>`

When the user clicks on the link `Hello` i need to copy the text `Hello` to the Label declared above. How can i do this ?

Comment: Have never used it with ASP.NET.. But what about JavaScript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple JavaScript works:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="lol"></asp:Label>
<a id="myLink" onclick="linkClick()"> Hello </a>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function linkClick() {
        var value = document.getElementById('myLink').innerText;
        document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').innerText = value;
    }
</script>
```

Or as Devang Rathod suggested you can use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jquery`for that. but you have to jquery.js on your page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function() {
    $("#Label1").attr('Text',$("a").text());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Markup:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=" "></asp:Label>
<asp:LinkButton id="button" runat="server" Text="Hello" onClick="button_onclick" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void button_onclick(Object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = button.Text;
}
```